# How to open old .doc word file on Mac that has equations?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have an old word file which is .doc, It has graphs and equations in, when I open with my word which is the latest version, it doesn't display them properly. they are all stretched out. I'm using a Mac. please tell me how can I open this file so that I can recover the graphs and the equations. Thank you!
PS. I do not have access to an older Microsoft word.

Answer (score 3):

First, check that your Mac has the fonts used in the Word document. You might be able to find their names by examining the file in a text editor. You can install Microsoft and other TTF fonts from the web once you've identified them.

You also might try free [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/?type=mac-x86_64&version=6.0.3&lang=am) for Mac, which can open a *great* variety of document formats, including the older uncompressed MS Word .DOC, as well as Word Perfect and other less common file types. The only negative aspect is downloading and installing an almost 300 MB file, but it can easily be removed if it doesn't work for you.